# Getting tag or index for a tap gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift3

I have a uitapgesturerecognizer, for a uiview. I have 30 of these uiviews in a scrollview. Also in each of these views there is a label with different words in it for each view. Now when I hit a tap gesture recognizer, I want to access the text from the label for that particular view. Whats happening is I'm printing the words of the last view in the index. Can someone show me how I can access each view in each index.

```
open var Name: UILabel!
open func ynCategoryButtonClicked(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let text = Name.text else { return }
    ynSearch.appendSearchHistories(value: text)
    self.delegate?.ynCategoryButtonClicked(text: text)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The place where you are assigning your tapGesture to your "UIButtonView", add this line:

```
yourButton.accessibilityHint = "YourText"
```

And In your "buttonTapped()" method get the text like this:

```
let yourText = "\(sender.accessibilityHint)"
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it sounds like you should be using a UITableView. Either way though, you should alter your delegate method `ynCategoryButtonClicked` to also pass a reference to itself (so something like `delegate?.ynCategoryButtonClicked(text: text, ynCategory: self)`). Then if you go the TableView route you can find the index by using `indexPath(for:UITableViewCell)`. Or, if you stick with the scrollview, you should be able to maintain an array of the views, and just search through them for the `ynCategory`.